# Display parsed data in info window in Google Maps

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework, infowindow

I am having trouble trying to display the event name from an array of objects in a parsed JSON file within Google Maps Ionic framework. Right now I have the markers displaying for each event with a simple string called "testing" which displays fine. The problem is I am unsure of how to display each events name within this info window and not the string I made. Any help would be appreciated. I'll post the sample image I have now as well as the info window functionality below. Thanks!

**what I have displaying now:**

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJbDu.jpg)

**marker/info window functionality:**

```
getMarkers(){
//this.http.get('assets/data/markers.json').map((res)=>res.json()).subscribe(data=>{
  this.http.get('http://app.toronto.ca/cc_sr_v1_app/data/edc_eventcal_APR?limit=500').map((res)=>res.json()).subscribe(data=>{
this.addMarkersMap(data);
});
}


addMarkersMap(markers){
for(let marker of markers)
{
 var loc = marker.calEvent.locations[0]['coords'];

  console.log(loc);


  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: loc,
  map: this.map,

  });


  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
   content: markers.eventName

}); 

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(str)
{ 
   return function() {
           infoWindow.setContent(str);
           infoWindow.open(this.map, marker);
                     }
}(markers.eventName));

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I correct myself. You could benefit from a closure here.
Use a self-calling function to seal your parameter to the infowindow:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(str)
                   { 
                      return function() {
                              infoWindow.setContent(str);
                              infoWindow.open(this.map, marker);
                                        }
                   }(markers.calEvent.eventName));
```

Comment: for some reason the info window just shows up with nothing when I apply that change

Comment: I have updated my code to that suggestion, but it still shows an empty info window for some reason. I pasted the code above.

Comment: Remove the infowindow content setting (in infowindow initial value) from previous answer and set it back to 'testing' or some such value. Then retry above ans.

Comment: I tried it with the content: "testing" and without the content testing with the above solution and still shows up blank. It must have a problem displaying the data for some reason.

Comment: See the edit. It should be markers.calEvent.eventName.

Comment: When I apply that change it says it "Cannot read property "eventName" of undefined. Yet when I do it to your original suggestion it doesn't give an error just shows blank.